# Run R command without entering R and without a script

Tags: r, makefile, console

I want to run an R command from command line (actually, from within a Makefile). The command is `roxygen2::roxygenise()`, if it is relevant. I don't want to create a new file and run that as a script - that will just clutter my directory. 
In python, this is simple - you write `python -c "import antigravity"`.
I use the Makefile to build, install and test a (Rcpp) package I'm working on.

Comment: `R -e "roxygen2::roxygenise()"` will evaluate the expression supplied. If the startup messages annoy you, `--slave` suppresses everything but the output of the expression. [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) is another possibility.

Comment: @alistaire awesome, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally done with so 'shebang scripts'.

Historically, [littler](https://cran.r-project.org/package=littler) was there first, about a decade or so ago. It is still widely used, and contains a number of helper scripts as for example [roxy.r](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/inst/examples/roxy.r) which does just what you desire: run `roxygen2::roxygenize()`. I use this all the time.

Next, `Rscript` started to ship with R. It is similar to [littler](https://cran.r-project.org/package=littler) but automatically available whereever R is which is a plus. On the minus side, it starts slower, and fails to load the `methods` package which is a source of a number of bug reports and SO questions.

Much more recently, R itself added the ability to run expressions following the `-e ...` switch.

So you have plenty of choices. You can also study plenty of `src/Makevars` files many of which use `Rscript`.